# Cannot find MDX module in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, gatsby

I'm making a Gatsby site, and I've intially set it up to use markdown files via `gatsby-transformer-remark`. I've since decided to move it over to MDX in order to have a bit more freedom in what content I can use.

I've followed [this guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/migrate-remark-to-mdx/) to migrate the project from MD to MDX, but I keep getting the following error:

```sh
Cannot find module 'D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\.cache\caches\gatsby-plugin-mdx\webpack\output.js'
Require stack:
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-mdx\utils\render-html.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-mdx\gatsby\source-nodes.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-mdx\gatsby-node.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-plugins\validate.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-plugins\load.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-plugins\index.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\services\initialize.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\services\index.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\state-machines\develop\services.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\state-machines\develop\index.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby\dist\commands\develop-process.js
- D:\XXXX\XXXX\gatsby\.cache\tmp-4452-lp3aICfNr8bo
```

I've tried:

- Clearing cache and build files (`gatsby clean`)
- Updating all packages, including Gatsby itself
- Various ways to include the plugin in `gatsby-config.js`
- Changing it all back to MD, making sure it works, and then migrating it to MDX once again.
- Doing a build. Same thing happens as when running `gatsby develop`
- Deleting package-lock.json and node_modules folder and running `npm install` again.

Nothing worked. This has to be something really stupid to do with NPM or Webpack but I just don't see it.

gatsby-config.js

```js
 module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "XXXX",
    copyright: "XXXX"

  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.md`, `.mdx`],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "gatsby": "^3.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.1.2",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-in-viewport": "^1.0.0-alpha.16",
    "react-reveal-text": "^0.1.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-text-loop": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I should point out that when I go that location in cache that's mentioned in the error, there really is no webpack folder, nor output.js - so it really isn't being generated when I run `gatsby develop`, I just can't understand why.

I've also tried making a new project by cloning the offical gatsby mdx starter template, and that is working just fine out of the box.

Comment: Silly question: Have you installed the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` plugin?

Comment: It would be quite funny if that was the case, but no - not that easy. I've installed and re-installed it a few times during the whole process.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `package-lock.json` and re-generating again?

Comment: @Ferran Buireu Yes